# 'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I installed yarn using the following command

```
npm install yarn -g
```

Then it shows the following status:

```
> yarn@1.22.10 preinstall C:\Users\vdine\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn
> :; (node ./preinstall.js > /dev/null 2>&1 || true)

C:\Users\vdine\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarn -> C:\Users\vdine\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
C:\Users\vdine\AppData\Roaming\npm\yarnpkg -> C:\Users\vdine\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js
+ yarn@1.22.10
added 1 package in 0.962s
```

Then I added the yarn path to the environment variable

```
C:\Users\**path**\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin
```

but its still shows "'yarn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

What should I do now?

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I had the same issue finally installed yarn using .msi file. Looks like its ok. But did you find a solution how to install it through npm?

Answer (score 29):

### Updated Jan '21

The recommended method for installation Yarn is now via npm:

```
npm install --global yarn
```

https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/

Try adding `C:\Users\vdine\AppData\Roaming\npm` to your PATH environment variable instead of `C:\Users\**path**\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin`

### Previously

> The recommended method for installing Yarn is your OS tools instead of npm, check out the MSI method:
>
> http://web.archive.org/web/20201226122851if_/https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable

Comment: That link you shared says the opposite of what you said.  It recommends to install via NPM.

Comment: @JasonCheng Looks like the installation instructions changed around mid Jan '21 based on Internet Archive. This was the original link content: http://web.archive.org/web/20201226122851if_/https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/docs/install/#windows-stable

Comment: I fixed it by adding a path to C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\npm

Answer (score 3):

remove file `C:\Users\vdine\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn`
and run `npm install -g yarn --force`

Comment: Is it working??

Comment: yes, it works for me, the path should be `C:\Users\<user-name>\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn`